# WebClient get/post to https always timeout

Tags: c#, xamarin, webclient

I'm developing a mobile application using Xamarin. The application is consuming an API which recently released a new version using HTTPS instead of HTTP. When changing the URL to use HTTPS and adding an atuhorization header, the request get stuck and will eventually time out. The API calls work fine when testing in Postman for example.

All API calls are made from a portable library and I'm running the application on a physical device.

Anyone have any ideas on what I can do to solve this?

This is the code I use to post data to the API:

```
    private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostData(HttpContent content, string authKey)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", authKey);
                client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 25);

                var response = await client.PostAsync(BaseUrl, content);
                return response;
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

I've tried many different solutions, setting headers, content type and so on but nothing worked. I've tried using HttpWebRequest instead of HttpClient but with no success.

I've set up a C# console application and created a new clean Xamarin Android project. Everything is working in the console application, but not in the Xamarin project.

Comment: If you're testing on Android, connect the device to the Android SDK monitor tool and take a look at the logcat, it may yield some light on the problem.

Comment: I know it sounds silly, but I had this situation once: We included a portnumber (non standard http:80) in the baseurl setting of the client and forgot to remove it, when we switched our server to listen to default 80/443 ports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work in a clean Xamarin Android project but only when using [ModernHttpClient](https://github.com/paulcbetts/ModernHttpClient).

But when implementing it in my portable class library it still didn't work. Instead, moving my web requests to the specific platform project made it work! I ended up using an interface declaring a post method. Each platform project declares a "PostHandler" which the PCL is using.

```
public interface IPostHandler
{
    Task<HttpResponseMessage> BeginPost(HttpContent content, string requestUri);
}

public class AndroidPostHandler : IPostHandler
{
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> BeginPost(HttpContent content, string requestUri)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler()))
        {
            var response = await client.PostAsync(baseUrl, content);
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```